# Homebrew - installed elsewhere and can't run it

Tags: homebrew

I have incorrectly installed Homebrew to a different folder and now can't interact with it nor uninstall it. It is located in: users/pavel/learningpython/homebrew

Is there a safe way to uninstall it all or reconfigure it so I can run it?

Thank you

I tried to change directory to various folders, be it those under the homebrew folder or outside of it, but can't seem to run homebrew anywhere. At first, when I was not able to even locate it, I tried various solutions with the .zshr file and it was not helpful. So I see Homebrew in Mac Finder, but can't find a way to interact with it, it always says "brew not found".

This is what the brew executable file writes when I run it through Finder:

```
/Users/pavel/learningpython/homebrew/bin/brew ; exit;
/Users/pavel/.zprofile:6: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/pavel/.zprofile:7: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

Comment: Have you try removing it (`rm -rf users/pavel/learningpython/homebrew`) and following the official install guide?

Comment: Hi. Please I am just not sure - can't such a removal (not following official uninstallation method since I can't do that) cause issues somewhere down the line? I mean, other than having to remove everything manually, is there not some sort of setback because of that? Thanks!

Comment: If you haven’t used it yet to install packages, I’d say it’s safe to remove it like this and start the install guide again.

Comment: Thanks! I removed everything. Running Anaconda now. Landed a job which is half-IT so your answer was put to a good use!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388622/zsh-zprofile-zshrc-zlogin-what-goes-where), .zprofile is just another .zshrc but on zsh. Your error says it cannot find brew in the default folder. ¿Have you tried modifying .zprofile so that it looks for brew in the correct folder?

Comment: Thanks. I have the folders in my computer but even when I try the official uninstall it fails to locate Homebrew. This is how my zprofile looks like:

# Setting PATH for Python 3.10
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/learningpython/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

My Homebrew is seemingly in: /Users/pavel/learningpython/homebrew

Can't seemingly connect it

Comment: You cloud try to remove all calls to brew in your .zprofile and .zshrc and reinstall brew like normal. You can back them up before modifying them to make you feel safer.

Comment: Thank you. I had to remove all calls plus all files but your answer was helpful as well. Was really scared I would mess something up. Running Anaconda now. Also I was until now in marketing but now landed job in half-marketing and half-IT so your answer was put to a good use!